# Python IRC bot module help?

Tags: python

I was actually making a module for phenny bot 

is called welcom.py and it welcomes every new guy who joins my channel

Here is the code I used for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def welcome_message(phenny, input):
    phenny.say('Welcome to #example channel ' + input.nick + ' !')
welcome_message.event = 'JOIN'
welcome_message.rule = r'.*'
```

This code works perfect despite that it repeats the message 2 times, like this:

```
<phenny> Welcome to #example channel visitornick !
<phenny> Welcome to #example channel visitornick !
```

Why this happens ??
I dont think I did any mistake in code.. 
coild it be connetion fault ??

Comment: Does this happen every time or only some of the time?  What has debug printing shown you?  Could you provide more of the code so we can see what leads up to `welcome_message()` being executed?

Comment: No it doesn't happen everytime ! you can find the code here.. 
This is just a module Im trying to make.
http://inamidst.com/phenny/phenny.tar.bz2

Answer (score 0):

The error is obviusly not with the function itself, so my guess is that the trigger is occurring twice.

Try debugging a bit: put a `print` in the function call, and see if the event is indeed triggered twice.

Comment this answer when you know more, and I'll update :)

Comment: Hi santiago,
I dont know about debbuging much :/ Im new on python !

Comment: Just include a `print` statement in `welcome_message()`, test your bot, and then check the command-line output. If there is indeed two prints for each join, the event is being triggered twice. That could be the server, or the underlying framework for the bot causing the problem. You can work your way around that easily, test it and I'll help you.

Comment: Hey guys, I just checked it, I moved mu bot to another server...
and it doesnt repeat now.... i think it was the connection

Comment: When debugging, you have to try, first and foremost, to understand the bug. Find a way to repeat it, locate the module it's in, the function it's in. Close in on it. Supposed you found it the way I suggested: the function is being triggered twice, good, why is that? Either the JOIN event is actually happening twice (server fault), or I'm processing it twice (my fault). Turned out to be the former. :) debugging it's just logic and patience

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented [error](https://github.com/sbp/phenny/issues/14). However, it seems it is because of how phenny's core handles threading. It doesn't appear this has been fixed yet.